# One checkbox checked validation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm facing an issue here with checkboxes in Angular. Because of how the backend works, all the checkboxes have to have a different name but at least one of them must be checked in order to be able to submit the form.

So I created a simple directive that should just do that:

```
{
  restrict: 'A',
  require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
  link: function(scope, el, attrs, controllers) {
    var ngModel = controllers[0];
    var formController = controllers[1];

    scope[attrs.validateOneSelected] =
      scope[attrs.validateOneSelected] || 0;

    ngModel.$validators.oneSelected = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
      if (!viewValue && scope[attrs.validateOneSelected] > 0) {
        scope[attrs.validateOneSelected]--;
      }
      else if (viewValue) {
        scope[attrs.validateOneSelected]++;
      }  

      return scope[attrs.validateOneSelected] > 0;
    };
  }
}
```

This basically set's a counter and whenever one is checked, the number increases and when it's unchecked, it decreases and is valid as long as there are more than one checked.

Good stuff.

However, because the validators are only triggered when the model value changes, I still have the others tagged as invalid.

Given the nature of the validators the only solution that I can see to solve this, is to put a `setTimeout` which runs after the validation is made, iterating through every `$errors.oneSelected` and calling `$validate` but that looks cumbersome to me and thought I may be missing something and that maybe, this can be tackled in an easier way.

#### Edit

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IpSriM2UndCB6tvMsixX?p=preview) to play with it

Comment: Could you put a Fiddle or Plunk together for this?

Comment: Sure! I've added a Plunker to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down this clever answer to your question.

**TL;DR: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xQsXC31sT974nTC55uaw?p=preview)**

It doesn't use your code because I wrote it before your plunker, but watch closely.

Consider that you understand closures look at this code:

**ANGULAR|JS:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    var counter = (function(){
    var counterVal = 0;
    return function(checked){
      if(checked === true){
        counterVal++;
        return counterVal;
      }else{
        counterVal--;
        return counterVal;
      }
    }
  })()


  $scope.eval = function(checked){
     $scope.valid = counter(checked);
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input name="first_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1st" ng-model="st" ng-change="eval(st)"/>
  first
       <input name="second_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2nd" ng-model="nd" ng-change="eval(nd)"/>
  second
       <input name="third_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3rd" ng-model="rd" ng-change="eval(rd)"/>
  third
       <input name="forth_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4th" ng-model="th" ng-change="eval(th)"/>
  forth


  {{counter}}
  <button ng-disabled="!valid">Validate</button>
</form>
```

**Explanation:**
Closure by mozilla:

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables.
>
> In other words, the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the
>   environment in which it was created.
>
> **By me : A function that remembers where and how it was created.**

What we are doing here, is three things:

**First:**

creating a closure, with a private variable - `counter` -inside,
the closure returns a function that receives `true` or `false`, modifies the private variable, and return the value of the counter.

**Second:**

We create a function that will be used on each checkbox element, that will pass the current value of the checkbox, `true` or `false`, and will pass the counter to `valid` which is a variable on the `$scope`.

**Third:**

We disable the button according to `$scope.valid`.

You could also console log that value, to see how the counter grows depends on the amount of checked checkbox you got.

**Hope this helps!
Linial.**

Comment: Hi Linial, this looks *ok-ish* but this is not reusable at all and that was the idea of the directive. If I were to replicate this behaviour in other form, I would have to create the same logic just for it

Comment: Well I created this before your plunker, I'll customize the same thing to your plunker